# Shutdown script via GPO displays unwanted window

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, profile, gpo

Created a GPO to run a batch file on shutdown for domain XP computers - with the purpose of deleting old user profiles.

For this I am using an application called `DeleteProfiles` from *OptimumX*.

```
cd C:\
if exist "Program Files (x86)" GOTO Exit (Checks if XP or not)
if exist DeleteProfiles GOTO COMMAND

:CopyDeleteProfiles
md DeleteProfiles
copy /Y \\SomeShare\SomeFolder\DeleteProfiles\DeleteProfiles.exe 
C:\DeleteProfiles\

:COMMAND
pushd C:\DeleteProfiles\
start /Wait DeleteProfiles.exe /MIN:14 /Y
rem (/Min: # = Delete profiles older than # and /y removes yes or no prompts)

:Exit
End
```

It works alright, but a CMD window appears at shutdown with the output of the program.

How do I make it go away?

The real problem here is that users can close the program which causes the script to stop. If I can't make that go away, I would like at least to make the window not close-able.

Answer (score 0):

Looked up start /?, adding the /b parameter does the job

```
start /b /Wait DeleteProfiles.exe /MIN:14 /Y
```